# Replace text ignoring HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a simple text with HTML tags, for example:

```
Once <u>the</u> activity <a href="#">reaches</a> the resumed state, you can freely add and remove fragments to the activity. Thus, <i>only</i> while the activity is in the resumed state can the <b>lifecycle</b> of a <hr/> fragment change independently.
```

I need to replace some parts of this text ignoring its html tags when I do this replace, for example this string - `Thus, <i>only</i> while` I need to replace with my string  `Hello, <i>its only</i> while` . Text and strings to be replaced are dynamically. I need your help with my preg_replace pattern

```
$text = '<b>Some html</b> tags with <u>and</u> there are a lot of tags <i>in</i> this text';

$arrayKeys= array('Some html' => 'My html', 'and there' => 'is there', 'in this text' => 'in this code');

foreach ($arrayKeys as $key => $value)
    $text = preg_replace('...$key...', '...$value...', $text);

echo $text; // output should be: <b>My html</b> tags with <u>is</u> there are a lot of tags <i>in</i> this code';
```

Please help me to find solution. Thank you

Comment: With the example provided, I don't believe Regex can do what you want, because you don't have a concrete set of rules, it seems your requirements change with each different example you provided.

Comment: Okay regex cant.. Maybe there is any another tool?... The problem is that user (site admin) enter the data to be replaced, the array is dynamic

Comment: Might not be able to be done. unless you can clarify, if the string is "<b>hello</b> world <i>again</i>". and i want to replace "hello world again" with "hi there from earth". what is the output?

Comment: hmmm. I think if string "<b>hello</b> world <i>again</i>" will be replaced to "hi there from earth" (without tags moving) it will be OK for me

Answer (score 1):

Basically we're going to build dynamic arrays of matches and patterns off of plain text using Regex. This code only matches what was originally asked for, but you should be able to get an idea of how to edit the code from the way I've spelled it all out. We're catching either an open or a close tag and white space as a passthru variable and replacing the text around it. This is setup based on two and three word combinations.

```
<?php

    $text = '<b>Some html</b> tags with <u>and</u> there are a lot of tags <i>in</i> this text';

    $arrayKeys= array(
    'Some html' => 'My html',
    'and there' => 'is there',
    'in this text' =>'in this code');


    function make_pattern($string){
        $patterns = array(
                      '!(\w+)!i',
                      '#^#',
                      '! !',
                      '#$#');
        $replacements = array(
                      "($1)",
                      '!',
                //This next line is where we capture the possible tag or
                //whitespace so we can ignore it and pass it through.
                      '(\s?<?/?[^>]*>?\s?)',
                      '!i');
        $new_string = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$string);
        return $new_string;
    }

    function make_replacement($replacement){
        $patterns = array(
                      '!^(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)$!',
                      '!^(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)$!');
        $replacements = array(
                       '$1\$2$3\$4$5',
                       '$1\$2$3');
        $new_replacement = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$replacement);
        return $new_replacement;
    }


    foreach ($arrayKeys as $key => $value){
        $new_Patterns[] = make_pattern($key);
        $new_Replacements[] = make_replacement($value);
    }

    //For debugging
    //print_r($new_Patterns);
    //print_r($new_Replacements);

    $new_text = preg_replace($new_Patterns,$new_Replacements,$text);

    echo $new_text."\n";
    echo $text;


?>
```

**Output**

```
<b>My html</b> tags with <u>is</u> there are a lot of tags <i>in</i> this code
<b>Some html</b> tags with <u>and</u> there are a lot of tags <i>in</i> this text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. this piece of code should work, assuming you're respecting only twp constraints :

- Pattern and replacement must have the same number of words. (Logical, since you want to keep position)
- You must not split a word around a tag. (<b>Hel</b>lo World won't work.)

But if these are respected, this should work just fine !

```
<?php
    // Splits a string in parts delimited with the sequence.
    // '<b>Hey</b> you' becomes '~-=<b>~-=Hey~-=</b>~-= you' that make us get
    // array ("<b>", "Hey" " you")
    function getTextArray ($text, $special) {
        $text = preg_replace ('#(<.*>)#isU', $special . '$1' . $special, $text); // Adding spaces to make explode work fine.

        return preg_split ('#' . $special . '#', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }
        $text = "
    <html>
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Hey</b> you ! No, you don't have <em>to</em> go!
            </p>
        </div>
    </html>";

    $replacement = array (
        "Hey you" => "Bye me",
        "have to" => "need to",
        "to go" => "to run");

    // This is a special sequence that you must be sure to find nowhere in your code. It is used to split sequences, and will disappear.
    $special = '~-=';

    $text_array = getTextArray ($text, $special);

    // $restore is the array that will finally contain the result.
    // Now we're only storing the tags.
    // We'll be story the text later.
    //
    // $clean_text is the text without the tags, but with the special sequence instead.
    $restore = array ();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof ($text_array); $i++) {
        $str = $text_array[$i];

        if (preg_match('#<.+>#', $str)) {
            $restore[$i] = $str;
            $clean_text .= $special;
        }

        else {
            $clean_text .= $str;
        }
    }

    // Here comes the tricky part.
    // We wanna keep the position of each part of the text so the tags don't
    // move after.
    // So we're making the regex look like (~-=)*Hey(~-=)* you(~-=)*
    // And the replacement look like $1Bye$2 me $3.
    // So that we keep the separators at the right place.
    foreach ($replacement as $regex => $newstr) {
        $regex_array = explode (' ', $regex);
        $regex = '(' . $special . '*)' . implode ('(' . $special . '*) ', $regex_array) . '(' . $special . '*)';

        $newstr_array = explode (' ', $newstr);
        $newstr = "$1";

        for ($i = 0; $i < count ($regex_array) - 1; $i++) {
            $newstr .= $newstr_array[$i] . '$' . ($i + 2) . ' ';
        }
        $newstr .= $newstr_array[count($regex_array) - 1] . '$' . (count ($regex_array) + 1);

        $clean_text = preg_replace ('#' . $regex . '#isU', $newstr, $clean_text);
    }

    // Here we re-split one last time.
    $clean_text_array = preg_split ('#' . $special . '#', $clean_text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    // And we merge with $restore.
    for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < count ($text_array); $i++) {
        if (!isset($restore[$i])) {
            $restore[$i] = $clean_text_array[$j];
            $j++;
        }
    }

    // Now we reorder everything, and make it go back to a string.
    ksort ($restore);
    $result = implode ($restore);

    echo $result;
?>
```

Will output **Bye** me ! No, you don't need *to* run!

[EDIT] Now supporting a custom pattern, which allows to avoid adding useless spaces.

Comment: I see global variables and regex for html. Hence my downvote. Regex for html can almost always be broken, this is no exception.

Comment: Hum, and what was the question tags about ? It isn't because a practice isn't advised that it cannot be achieved.

Comment: And since we're in this debate, PHP is an awful language in many ways, but some of its functionalities make me love it. According to you, should I quit programming in PHP ?

Comment: Nope, but since you failed to mention (and even used) any of the two, I consider your answer not helpful. No language is perfect, but you could have managed without the globals, and if the question asked about preg_replace for HTML, you could have answered with that while noting it may not be the best course of action. Don't take me wrong, I'm sure you answer is **valid**, I don't find an answer that promotes bad practices **helpful**.